# What is the minimum required length of mirror to view full object if the mirror is convex?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

i want to find the Radius of curvature of a convex mirror. i have all the factors to calculate except for image height of an object and image distane. so i can find the image height of  an object from image processing but i m getting the value of height that i see in convex mirror and not the actual image height..so is there any relation between image height and the height what we see at the convex mirror. for plane mirror the height in mirror is half the image height(which in turn is equal to real height of an object). so any body can please help me how to find the relation between height of object seen in convex mirror to the image height.

Comment: What are height in mirror and image height?